# "Count cells that is between 2 times"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have random times in Col A that is created through a timestamp function.

I have another Col (Col G) with the hours of the day written in this format 09:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00 etc all the way down to 17:00:00.

Now I want to count how many cells in Col A that are between the hours of the day, for example how many cells are between 08:00:00-09:00:00 or 09:00:00-10:00:00.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTunl.jpg)

I have tried using COUNTIFS formula in different ways to count the number of times something occours but without success. Tried using a ARRAYFORMULA but also without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could need some sample to test, to see exactly in which format Sheets is considering your values (working with dates and times can be tricky). Here you have some options:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&G3,A:A,"<"&G4)
```

Or, with FILTER and TIMEVALUE in case there's some problem with formatting:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A,TIMEVALUE(A:A)>=TIMEVALUE(G3),TIMEVALUE(A:A)<TIMEVALUE(G3))))
```

As an array:

`=BYROW(G3:G11,LAMBDA(each,COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A,TIMEVALUE(A:A)>=TIMEVALUE(each),TIMEVALUE(A:A)<TIMEVALUE(OFFSET(each,1,0)))))`))

Comment: Hi Martin! Thank you for replying. Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kMncsplEp4yNEI5QAUVBULKo4SGH3MWiYsRya3qB4o4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi again! The last array actually did the trick! Thank you Martin!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
=countif(isbetween(A:A,G3,G4,1,),TRUE)
```

OR

```
=counta(ifna(filter(A:A,A:A>=G3,A:A<G4)))
```

[image]